# Automatically upload directory to dropbox in no time (whenever any changes done to that directory

Tags: cron, curl, dropbox

I installed the following [Script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/master/dropbox_uploader.sh) on my CentOS 7 terminal access.

I'll use this script to upload specific directory from the Linux to `dropbox`.

using the following command i can upload the directory manually.

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh -s upload /path/my/local/directory/ /path/my/remote/directory/
```

**My question here:**

I would like to automatic upload the directory whenever any changes done to this directory which can be determinate by directory size if I'm correct.

In a simple description: **I would like to auto upload my directory whenever any changes done to it**

How to done that? via `cronjob` or there's a better way ?

Comment: Did you take a look at Dropbox daemon? https://help.dropbox.com/desktop-web/linux-commands

Comment: @Panki dropbox is no longer supporting Unix so that's why I'm using a third party script.